# Python: create JSON obj from JSONified string in DB

Tags: python, json, sqlite

I have a text field in a SQLite database table that stores JSON. I want my Python script to query all rows and stuff each JSON string into a single JSON object (or string, since I'm going to send it through a ReST API).

What is the best approach for doing so? Note there will be thousands of rows.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there some reason that the obvious answer of just calling [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) on each string isn't appropriate here?

Comment: Or, if you're just going to send it to a (presumably JSON) REST API, why even decode it? Why not just keep the JSON from the DB query as a string and pass it as the string in your REST request?

Comment: @abarnert I must have been doing something wrong, because when I tried that, it complained that the object had no attribute 'write'. It works if I write it to a file, but that seems unnecessary.

Comment: @abarnert hmm...good idea. I think for both of your comments, I have to figure out how to take SQLite results and convert (if necessary) to what I need.

Comment: @abarnert looks like the dumps is the way to go. Thanks!